# unable to view a link in the header of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, view

I'm trying to change one of the headers of a table to a link so that the user can sort on that column (as per [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns)
the problem is, nothing is showing up in the header of my column. presumably this is some CSS issue/background color thing but i'm still a bit too green to figure it out.

here is my header (sortable is a method in my helper that returns a link_to):

```
  <table class="standard-grid mtm">
    <tr>
      <th class="first"> <input type="checkbox" id="selectAll" value="selectAll"> All<br/><br/> </th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Customer</th>
      <th>Resume URL</th>
      <th>Partner</th>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th>Assigned To</th>
     <th>Comments</th>
      <th>Sent To</th>
      <th> <% sortable "date_email_delivered", "Sent On" %> </th>
    </tr>
...
</table
```

here is the (presumably) relevant css (in application.css):

```
.standard-grid
  width: 100%
  border-left: 1px solid #676D6F
  border-top: 1px solid #676D6F
  th, td
    border-right: 1px solid #676D6F
    border-bottom: 1px solid #676D6F
    padding: 10px
    min-width: 70px
  th
    background: #505155 image-url("nav-tabs/tab.gif") bottom left repeat-x
    color: #fff
    font-weight: bold

    a
      color: #aaa
```

Comment: that may be true, but it doesn't seem to have changed anything

Comment: i've tried closing the input tag a couple different ways and it's still not doing anything differently

Comment: i even removed the input tag altogether.

Comment: Could you post your code for your sortable method?

Comment: i figured it out. check my answer. stupid typo. or rather, stupid-non-backwards-compatible-rails-3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since i'm working in rails 3

```
<% sortable "date_email_delivered", "Sent On" %>
```

should be:

```
<%= sortable "date_email_delivered", "Sent On" %>
```

Comment: Good call, I didn't even notice the missing equals sign.